# Most cost-effective GAE app settings?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, memcached, google-cloud-datastore

A GAE python webapp I got splits its cost about evenly into 1) front instances and 2) data reads. What I can think of reducing the costs for data reads is store more items with memcache. But I don't know how to reduce costs for the front instances. I'm using the F1 setting, how do I know whether other setting increase or decrease the cost? What happens if I enable the PageSpeed service?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About PageSpeed Service cost:

> At this time, the service is being offered to a limited set of webmasters free of charge.

Have a look for more information [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/pss/faq#howmuchdoesitcost). But on the other hand there is an article ([Enabling PageSpeed Optimization Service](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/performancesettings#pagespeed)) in docs that says this:

> There is a small fee for using PageSpeed ($0.39 per gigabyte of bandwidth in addition to regular bandwidth charges)...

About lowering front end instance costs you could have a smaller number of idle Instances as that reduces costs.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely use Memcache extensively and take care to keep cache in sync with Datastore.

Slightly increasing the Pending Latency makes AppEngine hold off spawning additional server instances for a short while.  If your site throughput is low to medium, the impact on performance should be negligible.  On the other hand, the cost savings might also be negligible.  It will not hurt to give it a try.